# I am trying to add the Tag (freefrom_tag) for particular compute instances in OCI using python script and facing TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

**Please find the error**
**update_volume_response = core_client.update_instance(instance_id=i.id, update_instance_details = oci.core.models.UpdateInstanceDetails(freeform_tags))
TypeError: UpdateInstanceDetails.**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

```
core_client = oci.core.compute_client.ComputeClient(config)
core_client.base_client.set_region('us-phoenix-1')
vol=oci.core.BlockstorageClient(config)
# Send the request to service, there are more available parameters to send in the request
lista = core_client.list_instances(compartment_id=compartment_id,lifecycle_state="STOPPED")

for i in lista.data:
    inst=core_client.get_instance(instance_id=i.id)
    #print(inst.data)
    update_volume_response = core_client.update_instance(update_instance_details = oci.core.models.UpdateInstanceDetails(freefrom_tag={"shutdown": "no"}))
    print(update_volume_response) 
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update instance API requires instanceId as a required parameter that seems to be missing in your code. You can then provide freeform_tags (not freefrom_tag) as an optional attribute.

API reference - https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/Instance/UpdateInstance

Here is the sample that worked for me:

```
core_client = oci.core.compute_client.ComputeClient(config)
core_client.base_client.set_region('us-phoenix-1')
# Send the request to service, there are more available parameters to send in the request
lista = core_client.list_instances(compartment_id=compartment_id,lifecycle_state="STOPPED")


for i in lista.data:
  update_instance_response = core_client.update_instance(
  instance_id=i.id,
  update_instance_details=oci.core.models.UpdateInstanceDetails(
        freeform_tags={
        'shutdown': 'no'})
   )
   break
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please share the python sdk to remove the freefrom_tags.